# Disable focus for scrollbars in custom control

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, scrollbar

I've written a custom control in Windows Forms. I dynamically create a vertical scrollbar and capture changes of its value.

Currently, the scrollbar is the only control, which can acquire focus, so my control acts as panel: it transfers focus to the scrollbar. When user uses the scrollbar, all further keyboard events are transfered to it, instead of control itself.

I wish to disable focus for scrollbar completely and implement appropriate behaviors in the control itself (eg. Page up, page down, home, end etc.). I found a property named "CanFocus", but unfortunatelly it's read-only.

How can I disable the focusing ability for the scrollbar? I know, that I can implement the Focus event and manually transfer the focus to the control, but maybe there is a ready solution in the WF libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Łukasz O. for help.

The solution:

```
public class MyVScrollBar : VScrollBar
{
    public MyVScrollBar()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
    }
}
```

---

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("KeyDown: " + e.KeyCode.ToString());
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }

    protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Up || keyData == Keys.Down || keyData == Keys.Left || keyData == Keys.Right)
            return true;
        else
            return base.IsInputKey(keyData);
    }

    public UserControl1()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);

        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```